# MS Access VBA DSUM Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been trying variations of this for a couple of hours and it has me stumped.

I need to count the quantity of something in a table if a different column in the same table = YES. This is what I have...

```
= DSum("PO_Qty", "DeliveryByMonth_2_tbl", "[LIFNR]='" & [Combo524] & " And [M_0]=YES" & "'")
```

Any help is appreciated!

MS ACCESS 2010

Answer (score 1):

I always find the answer right after I post! The below works perfectly. Stupid syntax error.

```
Me.ThisMonth = DSum("PO_Qty", "DeliveryByMonth_2_tbl", "[LIFNR]='" & [Combo524] & "' And [M_0]='YES'")
```